# Facebook Like Count seems to be swapped on two different pages

Tags: facebook-graph-api, web, seo

Our site, http://offerletter.io, has gone through two rounds of domain swapping - first, one that added www, and another that added https.

I've been faced with an odd situation where the front page has zero Likes:

https://www.offerletter.io

But the Blog page has all the front page likes.

https://www.offerletter.io/blog
( 700ish )

But... the Facebook debugger is reporting that both pages have 0 likes (!?!)

Any suggestions?

I have three levers at my disposal here, AFAIK:

> The `og:url` property
>
> the `og:secure_url` property
>
> The `data-href` link I'm linking to in the Like widget

Answer (score 3):

You should decide which is the canonical homepage URL you want our crawler to use.

- On `https://www.offerletter.io` you have a (canonical) `og:url` of `http://offerletter.io/` so our crawler follows that
- On `http://offerletter.io/` your server sends a `301 Redirect` back to `https://www.offerletter.io`

This creates an endless loop. Since http://offerletter.io/ has the ~700 likes you'll want to make sure that this URL is where our crawler always ends up, no matter which homepage URL it starts at.

Here's some advice for accomplishing that:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler#updating

Comment: Thank you! Will take a look :-)

Comment: Ah, I see! So I thought initially that the og:url/og:secure_url properties were just keys into some index of Likes. But it looks like the `og:url` and `og:secure_url` properties are actually followed by the crawler every time they're specified in the page, which makes sense why I would need to add an exception for the Facebook spider.

Comment: Okay, this is interesting... It looks like the correct Like count is displaying on the front page now, yay!  https://www.offerletter.io/ Did ya'll change something on your end?